# How to build a model in Python which will allow me to have discussion(question - answer) with my data which is in csv format?

Tags: bert-language-model, openai-api, huggingface, nlp-question-answering

[image]I have the above dataset. I want to create a model which allows me to ask questions to the data and answers them correctly, my questions are not predefined and depend on the user at that particular time. What should I do ?
Example of my questions : What is the total Stock present for "Babyhug" brand?
What is the total Stock available for each "Category" ?
What are the top 10 costliest products ?

I need output in text format.